# How to connect to an online MySQL database from a Java application

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, insert

For an assignment I am developing an application that need to perform insertions in a MySQL database.
I am using JDBC but the hosting services I have don't provide support for JDBC.

What can I do? Is this method too old? Can you suggest me any alternative to basically insert from a Java application into a remote MySQL database?

**EDIT**: [image]

I wonder why people spend time editing old questions in a useless way... do you really care if I write mysql or MySQL? Does not make sense to me, you could spend your time actually answering the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not old, in order to connect to a database using java you need to have JDBC! start a simple JSP proof-of-concept in order to do that and probably you'll see it working. I don't think there's a host without JDBC support. Anyways, here is a really simple / insecure / old fashioned JDBC example:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
try {
String name=request.getParameter("name");
String address=request.getParameter("address");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdb", youruser, yourpassword);
           Statement st=cn.createStatement();
           int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into user(name,address) values('"+name+"','"+address+"')");
           out.println("Data is inserted successfully");
           st.close();
           cn.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   out.println(e.getMessage());
}
%>
```

EDIT: Please not that this is proof-of-concept, this code is vulnerable to SQL injection and/or needs to be improved.